# Promise resolving once

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, recaptcha

Promise in my code is resolving only at first execution, it is simple form submission with reCAPTCHA verification. From debugging I know the browser interpreter reaches line with `await captchaVerification()` and stops there. First execution works without any errors.

```js
contactForm.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await captchaVerification()
    const data = new FormData(contactForm)
    _alert.innerHTML = 'Sending message...'
    _alert.setAttribute('class', `alert show`);
    ajax(contactForm.method, contactForm.action, data)
        .then(([r, t]) => outcome(r ? r = 'success' : r = 'error', t))
        .catch(e => outcome('error', e))
});
```

Full context on hastebin: https://hastebin.com/oyuvoyeluv.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone wondering, this is the piece of code that solved my issue.
Basically Google API does not allow user to render **same captcha object** on **same HTML Element** more than **once**. I solved it by dynamically creating *HTML Element* for my captcha and removing it **after** I receive the response from the Google API server-side verification (success/error).

https://gist.github.com/ANTOSzbk/75ed7003e914162550f61399122a3bd4

Answer (score 1):

From the link you posted I can see that in you `captchaVerification` function, you check if a captcha has previously been rendered, if not you render and `resolve` or `reject` the promise. The problem is you never `resolve` or `reject` if `isRendered` is true.

```js
function captchaVerification() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        captcha.style.display = 'block';

        const verifyCallback = (response) => {
            if (response) {
                captcha.style.display = 'none'
                grecaptcha.reset()
                return resolve(response)
            } else {
                grecaptcha.reset()
                return reject('Invalid captcha verification.')
            }
        }

        // The problem is here as you do nothing if the captcha was 
        // previously rendered.
        if (!isRendered) {
            grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
                'sitekey': 'my-secret-key',
                'theme': 'dark',
                'callback': verifyCallback
            })
            isRendered = true;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I mean, `verifyCallback()` is called anyway according to logging. Seems like it is just not resolving.

Comment: Also you can't render recaptcha more than once on single element that is why i have that, and further use `display` style property

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you have posted you have the following options:

**1st option use `then`**

```
contactForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    captchaVerification().then((response) => {
        // check if response is ok
        if(response ... is not what expected end here) {
            return false;
        }
        const data = new FormData(contactForm)
       _alert.innerHTML = 'Sending message...'
       _alert.setAttribute('class', `alert show`);
       ajax(contactForm.method, contactForm.action, data)
        .then(([r, t]) => outcome(r ? r = 'success' : r = 'error', t))
        .catch(e => outcome('error', e))
    });

});
```

**2nd option use `await`**

```
contactForm.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let response = await captchaVerification();
        // check if response is ok
        if(response ... is not what expected end here) {
            return false;
        }
        const data = new FormData(contactForm)
       _alert.innerHTML = 'Sending message...'
       _alert.setAttribute('class', `alert show`);
       ajax(contactForm.method, contactForm.action, data)
        .then(([r, t]) => outcome(r ? r = 'success' : r = 'error', t))
        .catch(e => outcome('error', e))      
});
```

You could also try changing two-three lines in your `hastebin` example.

```
var isRendered = false;
async function captchaVerification() {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        captcha.style.display = 'block'
        const verifyCallback = (response) => {
            if (response) {
                captcha.style.display = 'none'
                grecaptcha.reset()
                return resolve(response)
            } else {
                grecaptcha.reset()
                return reject('Invalid captcha verification.')
            }
        }
        if (!isRendered) {
            grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
                'sitekey': 'my-secret-key',
                'theme': 'dark',
                'callback': verifyCallback
            })
            isRendered = true;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not differ from earlier behaviour. I think problem lays in captcha rendering, captcha is attached to `HTMLElement` and when I hide the captcha with `display: none` then the same captcha returns on the screen with style `display: block`. I think adding dynamically created element with explicit rendering might solve it.

Comment: @AdrianSolarczyk i think you should declare `isRendered` as `const` check the edit.  A similar logic to what you want to do is found in this https://jsfiddle.net/5upy7xhe/.

Comment: If `isRendered` is `const` I cannot reassign it which is it purpose. Also my implementation is wrong because I didn't use server-side verification which refreshes the key for my website.

Comment: @AdrianSolarczyk yes you right i edited my answer using var instead of let, but i don't really think this is the issue. Anyway i am sorry i could not be helpful, but i am glad if you have worked your way with it, best regards.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Your answer helped me to understand my issue and was helpful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It purely depends on `captchaVerification` implementation. If function return the same promise. It won't resolve next time. It is like `Singelton`. so better create `new promise` always.

```
const promise = new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100, Math.random()))
const captchaVerification = () => promise;

const captchaVerificationRe = () => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100, Math.random()));

async function main() {
  let res = await captchaVerification();
  console.log(res); // 0.3251446189302283
  res = await captchaVerification("sffsfs");
  console.log(res); // 0.3251446189302283

  res = await captchaVerificationRe();
  console.log(res); // 0.06299211055753262
  res = await captchaVerification("sffsfs");
  console.log(res); // 0.721527810718094
}
main();
```

Comment: Am I not always creating new promise within `captchaVerification()` block? I can't tell the difference between my implementation and yours